# CSS Browser compatibility issues creating borders

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

**HTML** markup:

```
<table class='cardc'>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='5' width='10%'>
            <img src='http://fwfn.ca/sites/default/files/pictures/blank_person.jpg' height='120' width='100'/>
        </td>
        <td width='70%' colspan='3'>"
                ."<a href='".$profilePage."&sid=".$sfid."#box-one'>".($record->fields->FirstName)." ".($record->fields->LastName)."</a></font>
        </td>
        <td>
            ".$record->fields->Email."
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='greyF' colspan='3'>
            ".$record->fields->Country_of_Citizenship__c."
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class='greyF'>year</div>".$record->fields->Fellowship_year__c."
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class='greyF'>Organization</div>".$record->fields->Partner_Organization__c."
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class='greyF'>Country</div>".$record->fields->Fellowship_Country__c."
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='3'>
                <div class='greyF'>Education</div>".$record->fields->Education__c."
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS** markup:

```
.cardc {
    border: 5px outset white;
    padding: 3px;
    width:80%;
}
```

But as the title says, I'm having cross Browser issues, the border that's supposed to cover the whole table gets cut off at the bottom.

Any recommendations for alternative ways to create the border?

Edited HTML taking everybody's worries into consideration. Border still draws improperly.
See a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b3yFJ/)

Comment: what are the cross browser issues

Comment: The border that's supposed to cover the whole table gets cut off at the bottom.

Comment: If you are still using table layouts to style your pages, it is not a good idea anymore, it was an old school way when CSS was still lacking. Semantics is very important now, specially for SEO.

Comment: Could you direct me to a better way on doing this? been trying to find a better way to do this for a while now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused by a combination of an invalid rowspan and border collapsing (which is the default when you select "Normalized CSS" in jsFiddle). If you turn that off or provide the correct number of rows then the border draws correctly.

Comment: I tried a sample where I had 5 rows of random garbage strings, still had a half broken border.

Answer (score 1):

`<td rowspan='5' width=10%>` indicates that there are at least 4 following rows, since the current cell shall span 5 rows. Since you don't provide any of those rows the `<td>` will spill out of the table. Drop the `rowspan` attribute:

```
<td style="width:10%">
  <img src='http://fwfn.ca/sites/default/files/pictures/blank_person.jpg' height='120' width='100'/>
</td>
```

Comment: According to both [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/tabular-data.html#attr-tdth-rowspan) and [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#adef-rowspan) it isn't. And if your code breaks in every browser except IE then it's because IE ignores an invalid value. By the way: if you wan't to span all rows you can use `rowspan=0`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `rowspan="5"` on the first `td` which is breaking the bottom border of the table, probably because it cannot find the remaining 4 rows to merge with. Removing the rowspan fixes the border.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3e9m/

Comment: The rowspan is not an issue, you can keep adding more td tags and it'll just stack them up. The current code works fine in IE, there's just some issues in chrome

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing the errors with html in your code, for starters. Your code lacks some quotation marks, and styling attributes in tags are deprecated.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .cardc {
            border: 5px outset white;
            padding: 3px;
            width:80%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class='cardc' style="height:100px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:10%">
                <img src='http://fwfn.ca/sites/default/files/pictures/blank_person.jpg' style="height:120px;width:100px;"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Notice I also fixed the rowspan issue, as well as the deprecated tag styling. And the original code could only have been interpreted correctly by an amazing browser.

Comment: rowspan is not the issue, I just checked.

Comment: In which browsers are you experiencing the issues? That would help a lot.

Comment: My code works fine in the latest version of Chrome. http://i45.tinypic.com/sg4bq8.png

Answer (score 0):

Lack of quotation marks and units.you need to specify whether your values  are in pixels or ems ....try and use color coding codes, eg #fff or rgb(255 255 255) instead of of saying  white.